# R select rows based on if else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, subset, plyr

I'm having trouble restricting a dataset based on an if else condition.

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
mydf<-data.frame(chemical=c("Cd","Cd","Cd","Cd","Pb","Pb"),species=c("a","a","a","a","b","d"),scores=c(0,1,2,3,0,0))
```

I need to select: For each chemical and species, if `scores>0` pick rows with smallest scores, otherwise pick rows with `0`

I can do smallest score, but I can't seem to add the if else statement successfully.

```
ddply(mydf,.(chemical,species),function(x) x[which.min(x$score),])
```

End table should be this:

```
chemical species scores
1       Cd       a      1
2       Pb       b      0
3       Pb       d      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workable solution here with OP's original logic, probably not the most elegant code

**plyr**

```
ddply(mydf,.(chemical,species),
           function(x) x[if(any(x$scores != 0)) {which.min(replace(x$scores, x$scores == 0, NA))} else which(x$scores == 0),])
```

**dplyr**

```
mydf %>%
     group_by(chemical, species) %>%
     do(.[if(any(.$scores != 0)) {which.min(replace(.$scores, .$scores == 0, NA))} else which(.$scores == 0),])
```

**Ifelse logic unpacked**

```
# If none of the values are equal to 0
if(any(.$scores != 0))
# Find the index of the smallest values from a vector where 0 has been replaced by NA
{which.min(replace(.$scores, .$scores == 0, NA))} 
# Else find index of value equal to 0
else which(.$scores == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(chemical, species) %>% 
  summarize(scores = ifelse(any(scores > 0), min(scores[scores>0]), 0))
```

I don't know if this is any faster, but just for fun, you could also do

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(chemical, species) %>% 
  summarize(scores = min(max(scores, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
  group_by(chemical, species) %>%
  mutate(zero = if_else(condition = max(scores)==0, true = TRUE, false = FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(scores==0&zero==TRUE|scores>0&zero==FALSE) %>% 
  arrange(chemical, species, scores) %>% 
  distinct(chemical, species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-zero)
```